# What is the Creeper?

Tags: inspiration, jeepers-creepers

In the film Jeepers Creepers we're never given closure over the creatures origins. Now that is half the appeal of the movie, but I sure am curious. In-universe, where does it come from? Out of universe, what inspired it?

Comment: The real question...where did he get those peepers?

Comment: From Justin Long.

Comment: I completely forgot that I always wanted to know where he came from! Good question :D

Comment: [You rang?](http://www.esourceengine.com/downloads/minecraft/creeper-tdesign.jpg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In-universe, all we know (that was explained in the movies) is that it is an ancient (at least 200 years old) immortal creature who hunts every 23rd spring for 23 days.  No origin is given.

Out of universe, [IMDB Trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0301470/trivia) mentions that Victor Salva wanted the 23-day hunt every 23 years because he didn't want a sequel (although this was eventually worked around by making the sequel occur during the same 23-day period as the first film).  Aside from that, he just wanted a scary terrorizing monster for a fright flick.  The directors have hinted that it might have originally been human at one point, a very long time ago, but it is not now.

Who knows, they might have plans on establishing an origin in [Jeepers Creepers III](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1139592/).

Comment: [Civil War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War) prequel?  (2001 - (6 * 23) = 1863)

Comment: How would have that prevented anyone from making a sequel? They would just say "23 years later" at the beginning of the movie.

Comment: @legomaker: Yes, but it at least means different actors most likely, and it means directors have to consider different clothing/setting/slang as the eras change. :)

Comment: Did you ever watch JC3?

Answer (score 6):

Out of universe, it's inspired by all the horror cliches and urban legends of the United States. There may even be a slight serial killer influence. Think of how the original movie opens... two college kids driving home through the backwaters. The protagonists are essentially stranded in the one place in the US where it is credible that they'd receive minimal help (after all, if it happened in DC they'd eventually scramble some fighter jets and vaporize the monster), yet it also has just enough infrastructure that the story isn't about them being alone out in the wilderness (where the challenges of survival are difficult enough that we'd need no monster).

We even see a cat lady for crying out loud.

Though not entirely analogous, we have to remember that the original urban legends are 1) the disappearing hitchhiker, and 2) the killer in the backseat. Thus, classic urban legends are tied to the concept of the road trip. Wikipedia would do a better job of summarizing these, but it's interesting how urban legends play out in such scenarios... perhaps it's because people feel the most vulnerable far away from home, from cities, etc.

As far as it being a horror cliche, it's difficult to name a horror author who doesn't rely on rural locations and on people "just passing through". Sometimes they're sacrificed by the townfolk, at others like in this movie, the townspeople do their best to fight off the monster. Lovecraft himself relied on rural locales of the sort that don't even exist today, up in New England of the early 20th century. Stephen King is no stranger to such stories. He has some road trip novels, if I'm not mistaken.

Doing all this with a monster instead of the more typical serial killer or psychopath is just mixing up the formula a little, makes it easier to believe that there is no escape for the protagonists (which, indeed, is the direction the movie takes). But we still have that element of there. The creature taunts both the protagonists and the police. He ends up never being captured or killed (sequel excepted), as mysterious as he was when the film starts rolling. It has that Zodiac Killer type of atmosphere to it, I think.

Answer (score -2):

The creature was inspired by a Halloween outfit my husband put together. An Australian Outback coat; a rubber mask purchased @ costume store and a black leather cowboy hat.   He then stood in our front garden like a scarecrow amongst other Halloween decor waiting for unsuspecting children to make it  to our door to trick or treat our house. Of course he would only "prey" on older children who could recover from such a fright-no toddlers were traumatized!  I have a picture of the display pre-dating the movie by a number of years. it is our "belief" that a child or parent of a child escorting said child has direct involvement in the creation of "the Creeper".

Comment: What? You're saying you were part of the inspiration? Need source if so.

Comment: I'll try to locate the dated picture I took and scan/post. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: @janedoe any luck in finding it?

Answer (score -3):

The creator said finally that he was a human in medical times until he made a deal with a demon but the demon tricked him therefor becoming the creeper

Comment: Hi, welcome to scifi stackexchange :) You could improve your answer by adding any source/quotes for your statement.